# Comprehensive Overview of the Literature regarding Meditation

Tags: reference-request, meditation, reproducible-research

There have been a lot of studies of meditation, but my understanding is a lot of it is put out by journals that have an invested interest in meditation "working" by whatever metric. Is there an overview of the literature that attempts to curate the things that we're most sure of? I'm looking for a meaty tertiary source, rather than say, a meta analysis. Ideally, I'd like something like a textbook regarding its effects and evidence thereof.

Comment: "best" and replicated makes this question a little broad. You might want to focus on replicated and the sort out for yourself what's best.

Comment: Sure. Do you have a set of lengthy overviews that I can sort through?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this domain myself, I was mostly referring to the fact you should edit your question to constrain it.

Comment: I mean, I've seen meta analysis that basically says "a lot of the research in this area sucks." I'm really looking for a tertiary source that compiles the best data in the way that a textbook serves to show the best data. I realized that this use of the word best is not super rigorous, but do you know what I mean? How should I rephrase it?

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yeah, I like the focus on certainty.